# Geometric mean of a Fréchet distributed r.v.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to compute the geometric mean of a random variable $X\sim\mathrm{Fr\acute{e}chet}(\nu=1,s>0,m=0)$, where the geometric mean of a continuous non-negative r.v. $X$ is defined as $GM(X):=\exp\{\mathbb{E}[\ln(X)]\}$ (reference for the [Fréchet-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distribution)).

I computed the CDF of $\ln(X)$ as $$F_{\ln(X)}(x)=\exp\{-s\,e^{-x}\}, ~x>0,$$ and if we differentiate the above CDF we obtain the pdf
$$f_{\ln(X)}(x)=s\,\exp\{-s\,e^{-x}-x\},~x>0.$$
Now I would like to compute 
$$\mathbb{E}[\ln(X)]=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\ln(x)\,s\,\exp\{-s\,e^{-x}-x\}\,\mathrm{dx}.$$ I think the solution is $$\mathbb{E}[\ln(X)]=\ln(s)+\gamma,$$ where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Masceroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). A quick simulation confirms this result. However I would like to compute it analytically somehow.

Maybe there is also a complete other way to find this geometric mean, any ideas?

Comment: When I run a quick simulation, I obtain $\ln(s)+\gamma$ as a solution.

Comment: What is the pdf of $X$? If you have derived the pdf of $\ln X$, then expectation of $\ln X$ is just $\int x f_{\ln X}(x)\,dx$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom yes, you are completely right, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometric mean of a Fréchet distributed random variable $X$ with probability density
$$
f(x | s) = s x^{-(s+1)} \mathrm{e}^{- (x^{-s})}
$$
is given by the formula
$$
\mathrm{GM}(X) = \exp\left( \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \ln(x) \cdot f(x | s) \,\mathrm{d}x \right) \;.
$$
Let us use the substitution $t = x^{-s}$ and the identity $\gamma = -\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \ln(t) \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-t} \,\mathrm{d}t$ to first compute
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
  \mathrm{E}(\ln(X))
  &=& \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \ln(x) \cdot f(x | s) \,\mathrm{d}x \\
  &=& \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \ln(x) \cdot s x^{-(s+1)} \mathrm{e}^{- (x^{-s})} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
  &=& \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \ln(t^{-\frac{1}{s}}) \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-t} \,\mathrm{d}t \\
  &=& -\dfrac{1}{s} \cdot \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \ln(t) \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-t} \,\mathrm{d}t \\
  &=& \dfrac{\gamma}{s} \;.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Now, we exponentiate this result to obtain the geometric mean:
$$
\mathrm{GM}(X) = \exp\left( \dfrac{\gamma}{s} \right) \;.
$$

Comment: That is what I searched for, thanks. However, the shape parameter in my definition is equal to $\nu$ and the scale  Parameter is equal to $s$.